# PipeTimeout with channel.recv after reading 9999 lines from windows openssh server using paramiko

Tags: windows, python-3.6, paramiko, openssh

I am trying to run multiple commands using paramiko. `Channel.recv` raises `paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout` exactly after reading 9999 lines from server.

I am connecting to remote Windows server 2012 with openssh installed from linux. Output from windows server has `ANSI sequences` and `H` code, so I could see `Channel.recv` waits for timeout after reading 9999 lines. `Channel.recv(buffer_size)` waits for timeout after this output `b'\x1b[9999;54H'`(9999 line, 54 column).

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)

interact = SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=60, display=True, buffer_size=65535, tty_width=100, tty_height=24)
interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)

interact.send('dir')
interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean

for i in range(100):
    interact.send('ipconfig')
    interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
    cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean

    interact.send('ipconfig')
    interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
    cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean

    interact.send('dir')
    interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
    cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean

    interact.send('dir')
    interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
    cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean

    interact.send('ipconfig')
    interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
    cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean

    interact.send('ipconfig')
    interact.expect(r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", strip_ansi=False)
    cmd_output_dir = interact.current_output_clean
```

I see `paramiko_expect` reads available data until prompt matches in the received output with `Channel.recv`. So, problem may not be with reading large output. Could it be a problem with data availability from the server? Can anyone help me to resolve this please?

**EDIT**
I have tried to reproduce this problem **WITHOUT** using paramiko_expect.
I still could see same issue. Before getting `PipeTimeout`, I see incomplete output from the command.
Here is the code:

```
re_strings = [r".*C:\\Users\\Administrator>.*", ".*Command:.*"]
default_match_prefix = ".*\n"

# Use SSH client to login
# Create a new SSH client object
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Set SSH key parameters to auto accept unknown hosts
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the host
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
client.get_transport().window_size = 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
channel = client.invoke_shell(width=100, height=24)
channel.settimeout(10800)
channel.set_combine_stderr(True)

for i in range(100):
    for cmd in ['ipconfig', 'ipconfig', 'dir', 'dir', 'ipconfig', 'ipconfig', 'ipconfig']:
        # import time
        # time.sleep(1)
        channel.send(cmd + "\r")

        # Create an empty output buffer
        current_output = ''

        # Loop until one of the expressions is matched or loop forever if
        # nothing is expected (usually used for exit)
        while (not [re_string for re_string in re_strings
                    if re.match(default_match_prefix + re_string + '$', current_output, re.DOTALL)]):

            # # Read some of the output
            current_output += channel.recv(len(channel.in_buffer)).decode('utf-8')

            # If we have an empty buffer, then the SSH session has been closed
            if len(current_output) == 0:
                break
```

Comment: For running commands like `dir` and `ipconfig`, it makes no sense to use "shell" channel. It only complicates your code without giving you any advantage.

Comment: Actuallly, I am running interactive commands on an interactive shell. Just for minimal reproducible example, I have given `dir` and `ipconfig`.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem *without* paramiko_expect?

Comment: Sure, I will do.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem __even without__ paramiko_expect.

Comment: For me that code finishes ok, without any timeout. Did you test the same with plain `ssh` (no Python). Like `ssh username@host < input.txt`, with `input.txt` containing the list of commands.

Comment: Same code works on linux. But I see this problem when I tested on Windows Server 2016 with latest Openssh version.

Comment: I've tested it with Windows OpenSSH as well. It works for me.

Comment: Did you get complete output for all the commands? In between, I have tried to test with plain `ssh`, I am getting `shell request failed on channel 0` error and commands not executed.