# Can I call Channel.invoke_shell() without calling Channel.get_pty() beforehand, when NOT using Channel.exec_command()

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko, windows-server-2016

I have read Paramiko docs multiple times. Still I am not able to find an answer for question I had:

Why can't I call `channel.invoke_shell()` without calling `channel.get_pty()` beforehand? – Here is my understanding from the docs – it is not necessary to call `channel.get_pty()` if I want to use `channel.exec_command()`. But what if I would like to use an interactive shell with `channel.send()` or `channel.recv()`. Is it mandatory?

Here is my try:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Set SSH key parameters to auto accept unknown hosts
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the host
client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
channel = client.get_transport().open_session()
channel.invoke_shell() # ---> Channel closed Exception here
channel.send(cmd + "\r")
```

With this I get `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed`. If I call `channel.get_pty()` before `invoke_shell()` it works. I would just like to use interactive shell but not terminal semantics. Is it possible?

Plink log:

```
plink.exe -T -v user@host -pw password interactive-tool.exe
Looking up host "host" for SSH connection
Connecting to host port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.72
Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
Using SSH protocol version 2
No GSSAPI security context available
Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (unaccelerated)
Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 255 xx:xx:xx:xx
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) outbound MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) inbound MAC algorithm
Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Using username "user".
Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Sent password
Access granted
Access granted. Press Return to begin session.
Opening main session channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Channel.invoke_shell()` without calling `Channel.get_pty()`.

If it does not work it is a limitation of your server, not of JSch.
And you already [know from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57932468/850848#comment102393976_57932468) that it is so.

With my Win32-OpenSSH 7.7 on Windows 10 Pro 1903, I can use shell session without TTY ([`-T`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty)) without any problem:

```
C:\>echo ipconfig | plink -T username@localhost -pw password
Using username "username".
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.356]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

username@COMPUTERNAME C:\Users\username>ipconfig 

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

...
```