# Read Buffer data continuously running on remote windows command prompt

Tags: python, ssh, putty, paramiko, openssh

I am connecting to remote windows host machine and executing cmd commands, which will start to print message on cmd screen. I need to pull the lines printed on cmd in real time using python.

I am using paramiko to connect to remote windows host:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host=host, username=username, password=password)

channel = client.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')

stdin.write('cmd_to_execute') # command which starts on cmd and start printing lines

# read the buffer in real time

print(stdout.read())

client.close()
```

I am not able to get the proper parsed output. Could some tell me the right approach to solve the problem

I get output like this when executed with 'whoami' command "b'\x1b[2J\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1H\x1b[0;39;24;27;37;40mMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.1482]                                          \n\x1b[2;1H(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.                            \n\n\x1b[4;1Hadministrator@win C:\Users\Administrator>whoami                     \x1b[2J\x1b[4;54Hwhoami                     \x1b[4;55Hhoami                     \x1b[4;56Hoami                     \x1b[4;57Hami                     \x1b[4;58Hmi                     \x1b[4;59Hi                     \x1b[4;60H                     \x1b[5;1H'
"

Comment: What does it mean *"get the proper parsed output"*? What do you get instead?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl updated with output

Comment: Also [Can I call Channel.invoke_shell() without calling Channel.get_pty() before hand, when NOT using Channel.exec_command()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58063024/850848).